# Puppet server can not sign certificate - FileSystemException: Operation not permitted

Tags: puppet

I have a pending puppet certificate:

```
$ puppetserver ca list
Requested Certificates:
    intern.mydomain.com       (SHA256)  3C:82:85:ED:6C:30:54:79:7A:FC:41:00:63:33:E0:52:BE:AA:3B:3F:76:21:73:1E:0B:1D:5F:A4:9C:D5:92:AC
```

As I try to sign the certificate, I get the following error:

```
$ puppetserver ca sign --certname intern.mydomain.com
Error:
    When attempting to sign certificate request 'intern.mydomain.com', received
      code: 500
      body: Internal Server Error: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/ca/serial6208651530228400767tmp: Operation not permitted
```

What could be the problem? The affected directory looks normal, the file in the error message is created and simple contains the string "0005":

```
$ ls -la /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/ca
total 68
drwxrwx--- 4 puppet puppet 4096 Sep 19 15:19 .
drwxrwx--x 8 puppet puppet 4096 Sep 19 15:17 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   1938 Jun  6 08:23 ca_crl.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   3862 Jun  6 08:23 ca_crt.pem
-rw-r----- 1 puppet puppet 3243 Jun  6 08:23 ca_key.pem
-rw-r----- 1 puppet puppet  800 May 16 13:33 ca_pub.pem
-rw-r----- 1 puppet puppet 1938 May 16 13:33 infra_crl.pem
-rw-r----- 1 puppet puppet    1 May 16 13:33 infra_inventory.txt
-rw-r----- 1 puppet puppet    1 May 16 13:33 infra_serials
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    226 Jun  6 08:23 inventory.txt
drwxr-x--- 2 puppet puppet 4096 Sep 19 15:05 requests
-rw-r----- 1 puppet puppet 3247 May 16 13:33 root_key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      4 Jun  6 08:23 serial
-rw------- 1 puppet puppet    4 Sep 19 15:14 serial3749210220972485837tmp
-rw------- 1 puppet puppet    4 Sep 19 15:09 serial4900578622956461009tmp
-rw------- 1 puppet puppet    4 Sep 19 15:19 serial6208651530228400767tmp
drwxr-x--- 2 puppet puppet 4096 Jun  6 08:23 signed
```

Any idea? Interesting, that I could sign 3 other certificates earlier (3 monthes ago), wich are working without any problem and I did not change the system in the meantime.

I'm using puppetserver version: 6.20.0.

Answer (score 1):

It was some permission problem. It seems that the error message was not correct. The file */etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/ca/serial* could not be written by puppet. So, the following command solved the problem:

```
$ chown -R puppet:puppet /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/ca
```